# Apache RewriteMap prg using fopen('php://stdin', 'r') not working over HTTPS

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, https, stdin

I've set up a RewriteMap using `prg` which calls a php script, like this:

```
 #!/usr/local/bin/php
<?php

/* DB query generates $map */

$stdout = fopen('php://stdout', 'w');
$stdin  = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
            
stream_set_write_buffer($stdout, 0);
            
while(!feof($stdin)):
                
    $input  = fgets($stdin);
            
    fputs($stdout, (array_key_exists($input,$map) ? $map[$input] : 'NULL') . "\n");
                
endwhile;
?>
```

And then .htaccess puts the output in an env variable MAPTO like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=MAPTO:${mymap:%1}]
  RewriteCond %{ENV:MAPTO} !=""
  RewriteRule ^.*$ http://myproxiedcontent.com/%{ENV:MAPTO}/$0 [P,NC]
</IfModule>
```

It works correctly over HTTP, but over HTTPS no input is returned.

I'm using Apache 2.4, PHP 7.2 and have confirmed that OpenSSL is installed.

What could be going on here?

Comment: By "no input is returned", do you mean that your script isn't receiving anything on stdin, or that the caller isn't receiving anything that you are sending to stdout? Also, is it possible that another RewriteRule is trumping this one?

Comment: @ChrisHaas It seems nothing is being received on stdin, otherwise it would be written to my log?  There are other RewriteRules, but if I remove them it still behaves as though no stdin is received.

Comment: Does LogLevel rewrite:trace8 say any of your rewrites are doing anything? Does it show your map lookup?  The rewritemap can't care about HTTP for HTTPS beyond the FAQ of rewrites needing to be per-vhost and not inherited the usual way.

Comment: @covener LogLevel rewrite:trace8 shows that with HTTPS it's performing the same map lookup, but it's not generating any input from my script.

Comment: @hwd how is the key passed to ${foo:...} calculated? No chance it's empty?

Comment: @covener I noticed in my trace log that it isn't performing the map lookup. Why would this be true only over HTTPS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I believe I figured this out. I think the issue mainly has to do with the fact that **I'm using WHM**, which processes Apache configurations in an extremely convoluted manner.

I had to scour the httpd.conf file for my vhost configuration settings. At the bottom of those settings - where SSL was being configured - was a comment, indicating that settings related to this vhost should be added to:

```
/etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/ssl/2_4/{USERNAME}/{DOMAIN}.{TLD}
```

I placed my RewriteMap setup here and now this is working.